# resharper search with pattern square bracket

Tags: c#, resharper, square-bracket, structural-search

how can I escape "[" in Resharper 6s Structural Search (C#). If i am searching for a pattern which contains a square bracket i just got the info: pattern is ambiguous.

Is there any documentation of the syntax? I can't find a syntax documentation on the resharper homepage except for the $VarName$ syntax.

Standard regex escapes like \[ \\[ where tested. They are not working.

Basically I want to do a search and replace.

Comment: What's the actual pattern you are searching for? I can find usages of `$dictionary$[$str$]` with no problem at all

Comment: something like this: [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("...")]

Answer (score 0):

Quoting your comment:

> something like this: `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("...")]`

Structural Search and Replace looks for **executable code**, which this isn't. To find what you want (the keybindings I use are the Visual Studio ones):

- `ReSharper | Navigate | Go to Symbol...` (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Type in `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`
- If R# doesn't automatically switch to searching library types, check the `Include library types` checkbox
- You should be taken to the definition of this attibute, in the Object Browser
- `ReSharper | Find | Find Usages` (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)

You should now be shown all the usages of this attribute, in the R# Find Results window.

Comment: Sorry the comment above was only an example. I want to do a search and replace of multiple attributes. I just wanted to keep the example simple.

Comment: Visual Studio's Find and Replace has regular expression support and is pretty powerful. Perhaps you can persuade it to do what you want.

Comment: Yes i actually did it now with this but it is not as comfortable as Resharpers Search if you want to search multiple lines